# convert wide format to long format

Tags: r, dataframe

At the moment, my dataset is in a wide format, I would like to change it to a different format
I have a data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Pat = c(88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 96L, 105L), res1 = c(63L, 
77L, 73L, 61L, 101L, 86L), res2 = c(173L, 187L, 179L, 171L, 174L, 
184L), res3 = c(369L, 519L, 669L, 719L, 619L, 419L), res4 = c(37L, 
32L, 34L, 35L, 30L, 33L), res5 = c(79L, 61L, 89L, 93L, 46L, 77L
), res6 = c(204L, 180L, 190L, 184L, 149L, 180L), res1.1 = c(495L, 
113L, 109L, 97L, 137L, 122L), res2.1 = c(209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 
209L, 209L), res3.1 = c(405L, 555L, 705L, 755L, 655L, 455L), 
    res4.1 = c(73L, 68L, 70L, 71L, 66L, 69L), res5.1 = c(115L, 
    97L, 125L, 129L, 82L, 113L), res6.1 = c(240L, 216L, 226L, 
    220L, 185L, 216L), res1.2 = c(413L, 563L, 713L, 763L, 663L, 
    463L), res2.2 = c(81L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 74L, 77L), res3.2 = c(123L, 
    105L, 133L, 137L, 90L, 121L), res4.2 = c(248L, 224L, 234L, 
    228L, 193L, 224L), res5.2 = c(539L, 157L, 153L, 141L, 181L, 
    166L), res6.2 = c(253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I would like to bring it to this form:

```
data <- structure(list(Pat = c(88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 96L, 105L, 88L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 96L, 105L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 96L, 105L), time = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), res1 = c(63L, 77L, 73L, 61L, 101L, 86L, 495L, 113L, 109L, 
97L, 137L, 122L, 413L, 563L, 713L, 763L, 663L, 463L), res2 = c(173L, 
187L, 179L, 171L, 174L, 184L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 
81L, 76L, 78L, 79L, 74L, 77L), res3 = c(369L, 519L, 669L, 719L, 
619L, 419L, 405L, 555L, 705L, 755L, 655L, 455L, 123L, 105L, 133L, 
137L, 90L, 121L), res4 = c(37L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 30L, 33L, 73L, 
68L, 70L, 71L, 66L, 69L, 248L, 224L, 234L, 228L, 193L, 224L), 
    res5 = c(79L, 61L, 89L, 93L, 46L, 77L, 115L, 97L, 125L, 129L, 
    82L, 113L, 539L, 157L, 153L, 141L, 181L, 166L), res6 = c(204L, 
    180L, 190L, 184L, 149L, 180L, 240L, 216L, 226L, 220L, 185L, 
    216L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

I tried to do this with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
z <- gather(data, Var, Score, -1) %>%
     separate(Var, into = c("time", "Var2"), sep = 3) %>%
     group_by(time = match(time, unique(time))) %>%
     mutate(Question = row_number()) %>%
     select(-Var2)
```

But it does not give out what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is a mistake but the 1st set of `res` values don't have `'.number'` in them. We may adjust the columns using `rename_with` and then use `pivot_longer`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~paste0(., '.3'), matches('^res\\d+$')) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Pat, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'time'), 
               names_sep = '\\.') 

#     Pat time   res1  res2  res3  res4  res5  res6
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    88 3        63   173   369    37    79   204
# 2    88 1       495   209   405    73   115   240
# 3    88 2       413    81   123   248   539   253
# 4    89 3        77   187   519    32    61   180
# 5    89 1       113   209   555    68    97   216
# 6    89 2       563    76   105   224   157   253
# 7    90 3        73   179   669    34    89   190
# 8    90 1       109   209   705    70   125   226
# 9    90 2       713    78   133   234   153   253
#10    91 3        61   171   719    35    93   184
#11    91 1        97   209   755    71   129   220
#12    91 2       763    79   137   228   141   253
#13    96 3       101   174   619    30    46   149
#14    96 1       137   209   655    66    82   185
#15    96 2       663    74    90   193   181   253
#16   105 3        86   184   419    33    77   180
#17   105 1       122   209   455    69   113   216
#18   105 2       463    77   121   224   166   253
```

If you don't want to hardcode the column suffix use -

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Pat, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'time'), 
               names_sep = '\\.') %>%
  group_by(Pat) %>%
  mutate(time = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup
```

This returns a warning since there is no `'.'` in certain column names but the warning is safe to ignore.

Comment: Thank you, but you can do something with ".3". do not enter it yourself, but get it with a certain shift?

Comment: Maybe the updated answer would help.